# react-native: animate height of Text component?

Tags: react-native

So I have a `Text` component, with a `numberOfLines` prop of 5. Whenever the number of lines of that component exceeds 5, it ends with an ellipse. Is there any way for me to animate the height of this `Text` component to show the rest of the lines that were automatically cut off?

ex.

```
<Text>
    asldkfjaslfkdsajflkfjsadfsadifjsflsakfjfalskfjfalskfjasflkasdjfas
    lifsadjfaisfjaflkafjaslfkasdjflaskfjasklsdjfasfijeifjsadlkfasdjf;a
    sdkfjadsfl;kasjfasl;fadsjflaskfjas;lfasjfasdl;fjksafl;kasjfl;a
    sfjasl;fkadjsf;laskjfaslfkjsafl;sadkjfl;asdkfjasdl;fjasl;fjasl
    ;fkjasdflksadjfalsdkfjas;lfakfjaslfkjadslfjasdlfjasl;fkjasdlf
    ;kajsdlf;kajsdflaks;jfasdlk;fjals;kfj
</Text>
```

Would give me

[image]

But I want a button clicked, and then for it to animate the height and show the rest of the text.
[image]

Answer (score -2):

To show the rest of the lines you can toggle the number of lines attribute value and to smoothly animate the height you could apply a css transition to the component.

```
<Text class="text-animate" numberOfLines={`${!this.state.buttonClicked ? '5' : ''}`}>
    asldkfjaslfkdsajflkfjsadfsadifjsflsakfjfalskfjfalskfjasflkasdjfas
    lifsadjfaisfjaflkafjaslfkasdjflaskfjasklsdjfasfijeifjsadlkfasdjf;a
    sdkfjadsfl;kasjfasl;fadsjflaskfjas;lfasjfasdl;fjksafl;kasjfl;a
    sfjasl;fkadjsf;laskjfaslfkjsafl;sadkjfl;asdkfjasdl;fjasl;fjasl
    ;fkjasdflksadjfalsdkfjas;lfakfjaslfkjadslfjasdlfjasl;fkjasdlf
    ;kajsdlf;kajsdflaks;jfasdlk;fjals;kfj
</Text>
```

and

```
.text-animate {
    transition: all .3s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in;
}
```

Note this depends on how react-native applies the given class within the component and and is subject to `<Text/>` API documentation.

Comment: This is react-native. So you are not able to use those css animations and classes.